# Passing Variable to Remote Computer with Invoke-Command and Get-CimInstance

Tags: powershell

I've been attempting to pass a variable in Powershell using Invoke-Command, however, every example I've found doesn't seem to work when using Get-CimInstance.  This is the basic code I'm using is:

```
$Computer = (Read-Host "Enter Computer Name")
$User = (Read-Host "Enter User Name")
$Cred = (Get-Credential -Message "Enter Credentials"  )
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter 'LocalPath like "%$User"').LocalPath.split('\')[-1] | Remove-CimInstance}
```

When I run that I get a null value:

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
     + PSComputerName        : DBServer
```

I've also tried using the -ArgumentList flag, but that doesn't work either and I get the null value error again:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter 'LocalPath like "%$using:User"').LocalPath.split('\')[-1] | Remove-CimInstance} -ArgumentList $User
```

or:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter 'LocalPath like "%$args[0]"').LocalPath.split('\')[-1] | Remove-CimInstance} -ArgumentList $User
```

My best guess is that the -Filter flag is causing the issue.  Though it works just fine if run locally.  Also in my test case some usernames start with a dollar sign (ie $fredsmith) which may be an issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

The doublequotes have to be on the outside to interpret the variable.

```
$user = 'joe'
"localpath like '%$user%'"

localpath like '%joe%'
```

This worked for me at an elevated prompt with the winrm service running:

```
invoke-command localhost { 
  get-wmiobject win32_userprofile -filter "localpath like '%$using:user%'" }
```

Or with no quoting issues:

```
invoke-command localhost { 
  get-ciminstance win32_userprofile | where localpath -match $using:user |
  remove-ciminstance -whatif }

invoke-command localhost { param($user)
  get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | where localpath -match $user } -args $user

invoke-command localhost {
  get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | where localpath -match $args[0] } -args $user
```

Comment: That seemed to work partially.  When running the -WhatIf flag it said that it completes, but when I run it on its own I get:
Invalid class
+ CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (systemprofile:CimInstance) [Remove-CimInstance], CimException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.RemoveCimInstanceCommand
     + PSComputerName        : DBServer

Comment: your code shows a WMI wildcard [`%`], but the code above lacks that. did you add it back?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Are you talking to me?  Ok I put the % in and some other stuff.

Comment: @js2010 - nope, i intended to address `roril`. [*blush*] i will add a new comment to that person.

Comment: @roril - your code shows a WMI wildcard [`%`], but the code above lacked that until recently. did you add it back?

Comment: @roril Remove-CimInstance?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - no had the % there whole time.  it's my understanding that the % is a wildcard, so i have it there for that.

Comment: @js2010 - i'm not sure what you mean?  Remove-CimInstance is a powershell command.

Comment: @roril That wasn't in the question.

Comment: @js2010 - i'm sorry for some reason i thought i added that, but apparently i didn't.  i've corrected that in the question.

Comment: @roril ok I showed how to do it you don't need to split

Comment: @roril - excellent! that was the only difference i could see ... i am glad to know that one thing is not the problem. i'm out of ideas so i will go back to lurking. good luck!